# Extracting numeric data from string using regex in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to extract numeric data from multiple string in a list, for example, considering the following string;

> '\nReplies:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t20\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\nViews: 20,087\nRating0 / 5\n'

I would like to extract the numeric data of views, i.e., 20,087 and the same holds good for replies, i.e., 20

I use the following regex code using python

```
    view = re.findall("\W*Views*:\D*(\d+)*,(\d+)", str(string_name))
    replies = re.findall("\W*Views*:\D*(\d+)", str(string_name))
```

I do get the following output;

> views: [('20', '087')]
>
> replies: ['20']

But, the problem arises when I try to run the same code for the following string;

> '\nReplies:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t20\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\nViews: 208\nRating0 / 5\n'

I actually get a empty list, which is not what I want. Also, I run the whole thing in a loop, for a list of 34 different strings.

```
    views = []
    replies = []

    for data in data_container:
        statistics = data.find("ul", class_ = 'threadstats')
        view = re.findall("\W*Views*:\D*(\d+)*,(\d+)", str(statistics))
        views.append(view)
        repl = re.findall("\W*Replies*:\D*(\d+)", str(statistics))
        replies.append(repl)
```

So, when I run in a loop, I get the following output, which is not what I am looking for!!

> Views:  [[('20', '087')], [('44', '467')], [('6', '975')], [('43', '287')], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

Since, I am missing out the numeric data which consists of only 2-3 digits. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/RwfXKS. I am not quite sure about the first case though: do you need `views: [('20', '087')]` or `views: ['20,087']`?

Comment: I would like it as views: ['20,087']

Comment: Then see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47177955/3832970) below. Other answers do not work out of the box, but if you want, you may "try". You may actually *use* my solution, no need to "try".

Comment: Thanks Mate, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest extracting a digit (`\d`) and any 0+ chars after it that are digits or commas (`[\d,]*`) to ensure you get the whole formatted number in the resulting list:

```
view = re.findall(r"\bViews:\D*(\d[\d,]*)", string_name)
replies = re.findall(r"\bReplies:\D*(\d[\d,]*)", string_name)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RwfXKS):

```
import re

string_names = ['\nReplies:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t20\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\nViews: 208\nRating0 / 5\n',
                '\nReplies:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t20\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\nViews: 20,087\nRating0 / 5\n']
for string_name in string_names:
    view = re.findall(r"\bViews:\D*(\d[\d,]*)", string_name)
    replies = re.findall(r"\bReplies:\D*(\d[\d,]*)", string_name)
    print("view = {}; replies = {}".format(view, replies))
```

Output:

```
view = ['208']; replies = ['20']
view = ['20,087']; replies = ['20']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Views\s*\:\s*([0-9\,\.]*?)\\
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(\W\w)*[rR]eplies:(\W\w)*(?<replies>\d+)(\W\w)*[vV]iews:\s(?<views>\d+,?\d+).*
```

It will give you both replies and views in seperate groups:
eg. for input

```
'\nReplies:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t20\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\nViews: 208\nRating0 / 5\n'
```

'replies' group: 20

'views group: 208

[See it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/O2LSIN/1)